# Form onsubmit returns false and still continues submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, prompt, onsubmit

I am using php5.6 and printing html and trying to get a confirm propmt to work with JS. Ordering products from weppage it should ask if person is certain that the order is made and he/she is proceeding to checkout after "ok". Cancelled to continue shopping or change personal info.

Prompt works, `if(!conf)` is executed and page is redirected to top, but it still submits the form and creates an order on cancel. Here is the code and that is included to other file if it matters. was searching stackoverflow for a while and didn't see this kind of a problem. Tried to put 'onclick' to button but it was even worse and got some errors.

```
ob_start();
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function continueToPayment() {
            var conf = confirm("<?php echo SQL::Translate('payment_confirm_text') ?>");
            if(!conf) {
                window.location.href = '#';
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    print "<form onsubmit='return continueToPayment()' action='" . SQL::Table("Pages")->Href("thank_you") . "?pm=cash&ord=$next_reference_number' method=\"POST\">";
    $amount = number_format((($_SESSION['sc_data']['final_total'])/100),2,".","");
    print "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='send_cash_order'>";

    echo ReturnOrderSubmitInfoHtml();

    print "<button type='submit' id='send_order' class='pc-btn pc-btn-sc'>" . SQL::Translate(PrintPaymentText('cash')) . "</button>";
    print "<br/>";

    print "</form>";

    $form = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the form part it should be `onsubmit='continueToPayment(event)'`.

Then in the function you need to stop default form behaviour by using `event.preventDefault()` method.

```
function continueToPayment (event) {
  var conf = confirm("<?php echo SQL::Translate('payment_confirm_text') ?>")
  if (!conf) {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0)
     event.preventDefault()
     return false
  }
  // else case unnecessary
}
```

Comment: It still submits form, but now after redirecting to top of shopping cart, the button that should give prompt gives error because there already is an order on that id so order cannot be created.

Comment: I have corrected what should be in `onsubmit`, also ensure you have `event` in parentheses in function definition.

Comment: The thing is that it still submits order on 1st cancel but then after it scrolls to top of page and send is pressed again, it says built in error because lack of information in order and prompt does not appear, so the kinda right thing happens on 2nd button press. Now i think it is something else than this JS.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for contributng to my problem! I have solved it, so the problem was that there already was a JS file doing check for term accepting and I tried to put js to php which was apparently overrided by that js file. I put

```
     var conf = confirm("example");
         if(!conf) {
             window.scrollTo(0, 0);
             return false;
        }
```

there and it worked. There was already an `event.preventDefault()`. window.scrollTo(0, 0) worked as the same as window.location.href = '#'. Anyway now I need to worry only about translations and make changes to other files than paying with cash.

Comment: Glad you figured that out!